# Can two XAML Files have one cs file in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Can two XAML files have one `.cs` file?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't think we can have 2 xaml files for one single cs file. But we can add a xaml file without having any cs file(i.e. resourceDictionary) and we can use it in Cs file.

Comment: @Nikhil: What is your requirement? Why you are looking for a cs having 2 xaml files? What benefit you will get if 2 xaml files will have 1 cs file then ?

Comment: @CodyGray It does make sense. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a95699b1-067b-4370-b6c4-7cfa5e67c213/how-to-share-same-code-for-2-different-xaml-files?forum=wpf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because the backing source file only contains a partial class we can move it to any place we want. However this is **not** desired practice.

UserControl1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="UserControl1"/>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl2:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="UserControl2"/>
</UserControl>
```

Source:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.

Although this can be easily achieved using `MVVM` pattern. You can save same `cs` file (View Model) for multiple `XAML` files (Views)

Can you explain why you need this? May be you are going for wrong approach